# What is the state of support by Netbeans for Bazaar?

Tags: netbeans, bazaar

[Wikipedia Comparison of revision control software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_revision_control_software)  User interfaces table shows Bazaar as not having Netbeans support. Is there development underway to provide this feature for Bazaar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so. As mentioned in [this comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netbeans/+bug/298025/comments/1) of [Bug #298025](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netbeans/+bug/298025) (see also its little brother [Bug 124436](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=124436) in NetBeans issue tracker), Bazaar is not supported out of the box:

> NetBeans team does not have resources to support every versioning system. But there is support for anyone who wants to write support for favorite versioning system. See http://versioncontrol.netbeans.org#community_support.

And I'm not aware of any third-party plugin (there is a [Netbeans bazaar plugin](https://launchpad.net/nb-bzr) on Launchpad but this looks like an empty shell).

Answer (score 0):

There is a [qbazaar plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/36216/qbazaar) which seems to work nicely.

(It looks similar to the eclipse qbazaar plugin - it is a thin wrapper around [qt frontends for the bazaar commands](http://wiki.bazaar.canonical.com/QBzr) - very nice!)